# date has already passed OR date has already past?

Tags: word-choice, american-english, british-english, speech

Which is correct : date has already passed , or date has already past ?

Thanks

Comment: *Passed* = past tense of the verb *Pass*. Past = Verbal-noun/adjective/adverb/participle derived from the verb *Pass*

Comment: Nothing has changed since being closed. Why would it be reopened?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*The date has already passed,* or the past date.

[Past:](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Past)

> - Usage: The past participle of pass is sometimes wrongly spelt past: the time for recriminations has passed (not past)
> - The word [past](http://www.grammar-monster.com/easily_confused/past_passed.htm) has several meanings (usually related to time before the present or to indicate movement from one side of a reference point to the other side.) Past can be used as an adjective, an adverb, a noun or a preposition: